# How can I inject same class with different Life Cycles on Asp.Net Core DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In the past, I used Unity Container to resolve my dependencies with Asp.Net MVC. Now I am planning to use the Asp.Net Core DI instead of Unity that doesn't have at the moment a viable way to integrate with Core, and I am trying to figure out which is the best way to inject the same class but with different life cycles.

Why? My question itself is coming because more than one thread operating on a single Entity Framework context was not thread safe and in order to execute a separate query in another thread I need a separate instance of my DbContext for each thread instance.
My strategy with Unity was creating 2 UnityContainers, one that had all singleton classes and the other that was creating the instances per request. So when I created the second query in a separate thread I just resolve it through the unity's instance created per request.

With Asp.Net Core I would like to know:

1- Which is the best way to solve my problem?

2- If I choose the same strategy I would like to know how can I have the same Asp.Net Core DI twice?, maybe applying a CompositionRoot pattern to both "containers"

3-If I don't choose my strategy, which pattern I can use to resolve in the same container an instance of the same class with different life cycles, and which is the way to resolve them separately?

Comment: I'd need to look into it but would named instances work? It depend on the DI you are using as I doubt that is supported out the box. In simple injector has this: http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key

Comment: @AshleyMedway yes, that feature depends on the DI you are using, but as the link said, I want to avoid the GetByKey to not introduce a ServiceLocator in my architecture

Comment: "Unity that doesn't have at the moment a viable way to integrate with Core". [This example project](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Unity/Startup.cs) shows how to integrate Unity with ASP.NET Core. The fallacy here is that you think you need an adapter, but you don't.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re asking for is unnecessary, really.

When you add a `DbContext` in the `ConfigureServices` (using the `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>` extension method) method in the `StartUp` class of an ASP .NET Core application, by default is gets registered as with a *scoped* lifetime. The scoped lifetime is required to get around the thread safety issue you mention.

Of course, you can override this with `AddDbContext` by passing some additional parameters. Or, you can register the context yourself. But, why would you want to(?).

Comment: Please read this section "Understanding Scope Lifetime" and give me your opinion https://wildermuth.com/2016/08/07/ASP-NET-Core-Dependency-Injection, seems like even in that way I face the same problem

Comment: The scenario he describes seems to relate directly to the fact that he wants to use the context within the `StartUp` class; to do database seeding. I still don’t think you will need to go through the trouble of creating more than one container, unless your application is quite complex. Scoped lifetime around one, or more, context should do what you need, without issue. That is what I use in my EF related projects, and it works fine. The only time I have an issue is if I inadvertently try to register a context as a transient, or singleton (all sorts of errors when attempting to DB I/O then).